# Installing mysql using rpm in linux through commandline

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql5

I'm trying to install latest version of mysql server. I tried to uninstall mysql 4.1 using rpm -e .

Once uninstallation done I tried to download mysql packages:

Command :

wget http://www.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-client-5.1.73-1.glibc23.x86_64.rpm

but it is throwing " temporary failed name resolution "

Can anybody help me to install mysql through command-line in linux server?

**Edited**

/etc/resolv.conf file

```
   nameserver 18X.3x.86.XX // added now
   nameserver 2XX.232.2.XX
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what the problem was with your attempt to uninstall mysql with `yum remove`. Your system isn't on the network, or isn't fully configured for the network. Start with getting network connectivity working such that you can do `dig www.google.com` and get a valid response (example below), then you should be able to use the `wget` command normally.

Example dig output:

```
$ dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24890
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         136     IN      A       74.125.131.147
www.google.com.         136     IN      A       74.125.131.99
www.google.com.         136     IN      A       74.125.131.103
www.google.com.         136     IN      A       74.125.131.104
www.google.com.         136     IN      A       74.125.131.105
www.google.com.         136     IN      A       74.125.131.106

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             69743   IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
google.com.             69743   IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             69743   IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             69743   IN      NS      ns3.google.com.

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 10.10.11.48#53(10.10.11.48)
;; WHEN: Tue May 27 14:20:30 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 200
```

Comment: yes.you are right. if I access using dig @<ip address> www.google.com ill get the response. So what will be the wget command?

Comment: You have to get the local nameserver configuration correct. The `wget` command you have is correct, it's not working because you have name resolution problems. Fix the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I have added ip address in `/etc/resolv.conf` file .Now I can `dig google.com`. But now both yum and wget command giving timeout error

Comment: Then you have some sort of firewall issue going on. But ultimately your problem is networking, not the commands you're trying to use.

Comment: iptables -L -n doesn't show any firwall